# How to quit loop when requirement is met in C

Tags: c

I have made a while loop and it works partly. I want the code to stop when the values entered are under the parameter, but it keeps going regardless of the output. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    // defining variables until "till here" comment
    int i;
    int rollDice;
    int firInp;
    int secInp;
    srand (time(NULL)); // seeding rand so that we get different values every time

    // till here


    while(rollDice > 0)
    {

    printf("Enter the amount of faces you want your dice to have (MAX=24, MIN=1): "); // prints the message
    scanf("%d", &firInp); // user input stored into firInp
    printf("Enter the amount of throws you want(MAX=499, MIN=1): "); // this message is printed after the users first input
    scanf("%d", &secInp); // user input stored into secInp

    if (((firInp < 25)&&(firInp > 1))&&((secInp < 500)&&(secInp > 1))){ // if statement to check parameters

    for(i = 0; i < secInp; i++){
        rollDice = (rand()%firInp) + 1;
        printf("%d \n", rollDice);

    }
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, these numbers don't meet the parameters\nPlease enter a number in the right parameters.\n");
    }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C btw.

edit: I want the loop to continue if the user input is more than 24, 499 respectively.

Comment: Your loop condition is `rollDice > 0`. And `rollDice = (rand()%firInp) + 1;`. In which circumstances the condition can be possibly false? It is also uninitialized in the first iteration.

Comment: "I'm new to C btw" -- I have a suggestion for you: turn on all the warnings your compiler can produce and read its output carefully. Try to create compilations with no warnrings.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes. ```rollDice``` will never become zero. because he's adding 1 to the already minimum number 0 case. He needs a flag variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong. Variable `rollDice` is for storing the values of the outcomes rather than doing a condition check. It will have random values and since the values on the dice can't be negative or `zero` it may not exit the while loop. I don't know what will `rand()` will produce so I'm just assuming.

The range for `rand()` is [0,RAND_MAX), including `zero` and excluding `RAND_MAX`. But because of this expression `(rand()%firInp) + 1` , you're adding one to it. So it will never become Zero.

You can use a `flag` variable and set it to `1`. When the `if` conditions are met, you can set the flag to 0. It will exit the `while` loop.

Corrected code :-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    // defining variables until "till here" comment
    int i;
    int rollDice;
    int firInp;
    int secInp;
    int flag = 1;
    srand (time(NULL)); // seeding rand so that we get different values every time

    // till here


    while(flag)
    {

    printf("Enter the amount of faces you want your dice to have (MAX=24, MIN=1): "); // prints the message
    scanf("%d", &firInp); // user input stored into firInp
    printf("Enter the amount of throws you want(MAX=499, MIN=1): "); // this message is printed after the users first input
    scanf("%d", &secInp); // user input stored into secInp

    if (((firInp < 25)&&(firInp > 1))&&((secInp < 500)&&(secInp > 1))){ // if statement to check parameters

    for(i = 0; i < secInp; i++){
        rollDice = ((rand() + 1)%firInp);
        printf("%d \n", rollDice);
    }
    flag = 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, these numbers don't meet the parameters\nPlease enter a number in the right parameters.\n");
    }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT :-

Also, division with `0` is `undefined`. `rand()` can attain value `0`. You should add `1` to `rand()` rather than adding to whole modulus. It can create an error if the `rand()` will give `0` as an output.

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RockJumpwa22 please read the edit. You still has some error in your code which is corrected in the edits.

Comment: Thanks so much! You helped very much.